# Best way to only run @BeforeClass method

Tags: ant, testng

I have a test class that has a @BeforeClass method and a @Test method. I am running the tests using Ant. I would like to know what is the best way to run only the @BeforeClass method, and not the @Test method. Here is the basic code layout:

```
@BeforeClass
public void init() throws Exception {
    /* Perform test initialization */
}

@Test
public void randomTest() throws Exception {
    /* Run the test */
}
```

I have tried making the @Test method part of a group, and then in Ant specifying the "excludedgroups" property to exclude that group. I have also tried setting the @Test method to be disabled. Neither of these methods worked because it wouldn't run either the @Test or the @BeforeClass method.

One workaround I have is to make an empty @Test method, and then use either method above, but this does not seem like an elegant solution.

Is there a better way to run only the @BeforeClass method?

Edit:

Here is how I specify the  task in my build.xml file:

```
<testng classpathref="test.classpath"
        outputdir="${reports}"
        haltonfailure="false"
        failureProperty="tests.failed"
        useDefaultListeners="true"                   listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"
        parallel="classes"
        suitename="Tests"
        testname="${test.name} Tests">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately decided to just put an if statement around every @Test method, and have the statement evaluate a System property.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the `@Test` method will work but you will have to have at least one test method on your class or TestNG won't run anything in it, so maybe add an empty test method? It's kind of an odd scenario to run a class just for its configuration method, are you sure this configuration cannot be put in another class?

Comment: In this case the initialization for a test is time-consuming, so it would be good to be able to have a way to simply initialize the test, and then manually go through the test steps to reproduce a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to @BeforeSuite it is run without needing an empty @Test method and excluding the method. You can also disable the test method directly with @Test(enabled=false).

Comment: If I replace \@BeforeClass with \@BeforeSuite, and then run several tests in parallel, then only one of them will run.

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I have in my build.xml file, if that makes the situation more clear.

Comment: You could also use @BeforeTest. I run my test not directly through ant but with an suite.xml executed by ant. Looks something like this    `<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Nopackage" >
    <classes>
       <class name="NoPackageTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>
 
  <test name="Regression1">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterSample"/>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>`
from [link]http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: If you use a suite.xml you can also exclude methods directly, but I dont know if then the @beforeClass method is run and if you can do that with ant